# Windows believes Thumbdrive is corrupted after plugging it in a Linux

Tags: usb-flash-drive, fat32, file-corruption

I have Linux on my computer, and I sometimes put files from my computer to a thumb drive to school.

My school, however, has Windows, and the first time I plug in my thumb drive, it believes it's corrupted. I scan, says that I need to fix it, and at the end of the scan, says that there are no errors on the thumb drive. Everything would then be okay until next time I use my thumb drive.

My thumb drive has the common Fat32 file system, and I never have any problem with it if I don't scan. Why is this so?

Comment: How are you removing the thumb-drive on your Linux computer? Are you unmounting it before removing it?

Comment: @user1751825 I make sure no processes are running on it, then I eject it manually.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Does it still occur if you actually shutdown the Linux computer before removing the drive?

Comment: you have to use the umount command,or GUI equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "scan and fix" message that Windows gives you is a catch-all message that can indicate a few different things (e.g. just the drive being unmounted incorrectly to actual filesystem corruption). My guess - based on it not finding any issues - is that it's not being unmounted / "ejected" before being removed from the linux machine.